# Getting my head around strtotime once and for all

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a date, in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` that has been pulled from a MySQL database. This date is saved to a variable `$myDate`.

I want to save the date, three weeks before this variable's date, to a *new* variable called `$otherDate`. How can I do this (and ideally, change the format of the date at the same time)?

I tried:

```
$otherDate = date("l d F", strtotime("-3 weeks", $myDate));
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) must be a timestamp, not a string, so

```
$otherDate = date("l d F", strtotime("-3 weeks", strtotime($myDate)));
```

But look at using DateTime objects instead

```
$date = new \DateTime( $myDate );
$otherDate = clone $date;
$otherDate->sub( new \DateInterval('P3W') );
echo $otherDate->format( 'l d F' );
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get your head around `strtotime` is to [look at the doc page for it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

The format expected is `int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )`

And the parameters are defined as:

> **time**
>
> A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in Date and Time Formats.
>
> **now**
>
> The timestamp which is used as a base for the calculation of relative dates.

Therefore `$otherDate = date("l d F", strtotime("-3 weeks", $myDate));` is not correct since `$myDate` is not an integer but a string in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

You must pass the `$myDate` into the string with the `-3 weeks` modifier:

```
$otherDate = date("l d F", strtotime("$myDate -3 weeks"));
```

Or if you want to redefine `$now` within the `strtotime` parameters:

```
$otherDate = date("l d F", strtotime("-3 weeks", strtotime($myDate)));
```

I would however recommend using [a `DateTime` object](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php):

```
$otherDate = new DateTime($myDate);
$otherDate->sub(new DateInterval('P3W'));
echo $otherDate->format('l d F');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I find procedural date manipulation ugly and constrictive, I'm going to suggest using PHP's awesome DateTime class.

```
$dt = new DateTime('2014-11-28');

$dt->modify('-3 weeks');

echo $dt->format('l d F');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the strtotime wrong way.
Check this:

```
$otherDate = date("l d F", strtotime("2014-11-28 -3 weeks"));
echo $otherDate;
```

Output:

```
Friday 07 November
```